# How would I reset/clear the content of a text entry box object with Adobe Captivate 2019?

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe, adobe-captivate

I'm using Adobe Captivate 2019 to make a custom interactive software simulation. I have little to no coding experience but would like to leverage Captivate's execute JavaScript feature to reset/clear the contents of a text entry box triggered by the user's clicking a separate 'clear' button. I'm aware that this very question was asked and answered several years ago on stack overflow but the solution offered there hasn't worked for me. Here's the code I've tried thus far:

```
$("#InputText_inputfield").val("");
```

I copied and pasted the above line in the Execute JavaScript Script_Window as the On Success action of my 'clear' button as per the instructions of the previously mentioned post. When I tried to preview my project in HTML5 browser window, nothing happens when the 'clear' button is clicked. What am I doing wrong? Again, please be advised that I know very little about coding so any solution described in layman's terms is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Assuming your Text Entry Box is named "InputText", all you need to do is make the F in inputField capital and your code should work.

Comment: @ChrisWalker Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. This worked perfectly!! Note to other Captivate users: in order for this to work, the retain text option on the Text Entry Box needs to be unchecked.